# SQL Return Percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying to create a query which will send me back the percentage of USER_TOT_REQS.

How do I get the result back with decimals?

```
SELECT  u.USER_NAME
    ,SUM(t.REQ_AMOUNT) as 'USER_TOTAL_AMOUNT'
    ,COUNT(t.ID) as 'USER_TOT_REQS'
    ,(COUNT(t.ID)* 100 / (Select COUNT(*) from TB__TOMBSTONES t 
    JOIN TB__USERS u 
    ON u.ID = t.CURRENT_BUYER__ID
        WHERE 1=1
        AND t.REGION__ID = 1
        AND t.OFFICE__ID = 1
        AND t.STL_ASSIGNED__ID = 8)) AS 'Percentage'
FROM TB__TOMBSTONES t 
    JOIN TB__USERS u 
    ON u.ID = t.CURRENT_BUYER__ID
WHERE 1=1
AND t.REGION__ID = 1
AND t.STL_ASSIGNED__ID = 8
GROUP BY u.USER_NAME
ORDER BY USER_TOTAL_AMOUNT DESC
```

Basing myself on a few examples I've seen on stackoverflow - Thanks.

Comment: Also refer this post [http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2008/01/16/beware-of-implicit-conversions.aspx](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2008/01/16/beware-of-implicit-conversions.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your counts are inversed. The outer select is less selective than the nested select (which has an additional `t.OFFICE__ID = 1` predicate... (unless you forgot that in the outer select?)

The expression should be

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) ...[nested select]) * 100.0 / COUNT(t.ID) AS Percentage
```

For increased precision, make that `100.0`, but that's probably not the main issue here... Besides that, your nested select doesn't join on the outer select's user. Instead, for every group, it selects all users. So even more correctly:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) from TB__TOMBSTONES t2
    -- self-join t2 to the outer user. No need to join user again
    WHERE t2.CURRENT_BUYER__ID = t.CURRENT_BUYER__ID
    AND t2.REGION__ID = 1
    AND t2.OFFICE__ID = 1
    AND t2.STL_ASSIGNED__ID = 8) * 100.0 / COUNT(t.ID) AS Percentage
```

Comment: My results are now ex: 13.223140495867. How do I go about shrinking those results to 13.2?

Answer (score 5):

To get decimal values, change your `100` to `100.0`, otherwise everything is implicitly treated as an INT.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try CAST or CONVERT -ing your dividend and divisor to DECIMAL type.

```
CAST( (COUNT(t.ID)*100) AS DECIMAL )
```

and

```
CAST( (COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL )
```

Problem is you're calculating with integers:

"If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If any of your inputs is an int try the following

Convert(Float, (int_value1 - int_value2)/int_value2)*100